# Closing Chrome Print Dialogue with Dialogue Close button cause No script working

Tags: javascript

When i close print window dialogue in Google chrome with dialogue close button cause the script not working.Every thing stop in my site like redirection the progress indicator scrolls continuous and nothing happens on click.But if i close the dialogue using cancel button every thing is working fine.can't figure out the bug either its in code or chrome?

Thnx

Comment: Do you use any of the `onbeforeprint` or `onafterprint` events?

Comment: Yes i have used onafterprint Event  objFrame.onafterprint = AfterPrint;
    objFrame.print();